# Angularjs UiGrid - Prevent editing the cell by checking data in gridApi.edit.on.beginCellEdit

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to cancel editing the cell in uiGrid by checking the value of the cell. Any idea how to cancel and how to let editing go by checking the cell value?

```
    gridApi.edit.on.beginCellEdit($scope, function (rowEntity, colDef) {
        if (rowEntity.status > 4)/**/
        {
              // Cancel edit so that edit never applies
        }
        else
        {
               //let editing applied (which normally executes)
        }

    });
```

Thanks in advance1

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.edit' ]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', 'uiGridConstants', function ($scope, $http, $interval, uiGridConstants ) {
  $scope.edit = true;
    $scope.canEdit = function() { return $scope.edit; };


  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableSelectAll: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    columnDefs: [
      { name: 'name', width: '30%', cellEditableCondition : $scope.canEdit },
      { name: 'gender',  width: '20%', cellEditableCondition : $scope.canEdit },
      { name: 'age', width: '20%', cellEditableCondition : $scope.canEdit },
      { name: 'company', width: '25%', cellEditableCondition : $scope.canEdit },
      { name: 'state',  width: '35%', cellEditableCondition : $scope.canEdit },
      { name: 'balance', width: '25%', cellEditableCondition : $scope.canEdit }
    ],
    onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      $scope.gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (rowEntity, colDef) {
     console.log(rowEntity.entity)
   if (rowEntity.entity.id > 4)/**/

    {
          // Cancel edit so that edit never applies
           $scope.edit = false;
    }
    else
   {
           //let editing applied (which normally executes)
           $scope.edit = true;
  }

    });  

    }

  }; 
 $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
 .success(function(data) {
   $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
 });


}]);
```

I hope this help

Comment: Thanks Shad, when I change a field, it does not applied to $scope but the grid still shows the new value and does not return it back to the current value